# Chrome Developer tools missing timeline views

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

So under timeline I would normal see options such as Events, Frames, Memory in the upper left but I no longer do.  I'm not sure what I did but what I have there now is two checkboxes: capture stacks and capture memory.  How can I get back the original setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They updated the interface, I'm pretty sure all the functionality is still available.

(In timeline view)
* Event mode is the default.
* Frames mode can be toggled with the icon next to the trash can.
* Memory can by turned on by checking the capture memory checkbox.

Comment: I encountered the same problem. I already checked the capture memory checkbox but there is still no information about memory. My chrome version is Version 40.0.2214.45 beta (64-bit).

Comment: I am stuck in events mode now too. no option to switch to frames mode by the trash can

Answer (score 2):

It is in-fact disappointing to see such a feature missing from chrome dev tool. FPS meter can be used to get similar information, but not as good as seeing info realtime in Timeline.
[image: FPS meter]

In addition to this, for memory details the following script from paulirish is useful,

https://github.com/paulirish/memory-stats.js

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It moved into Performance Analysis Reference: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference